# Using PHP to set a backup (alternate) image

Tags: php, simplexml

I'm looking to set a "backup" image as an alternate to my PHP generated image (pulling filename from SimpleXML)

```
<div style="background-image:url('//url.com/images/<?php echo $xml->IMGNODE; ?>.png');"></div>
```

Basically, if the above PHP code returns no value, I'd like to set it to a predetermined image filename rather than just showing nothing.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.if.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<div style="background-image:url('//url.com/images/<?= isset($xml->IMGNODE) ? $xml->IMGNODE : 'default_image' ?>.png');"></div>`

Comment: Well, that was easy! Time to start learning my conditional PHP.. Thanks!

Comment: @flipnotic So you know where to look, the syntax used here is [the ternary operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary).

Comment: @Frank: SO-Tip: At at leas one sentence that introduces the code you place in the answer.